# Should micro services follow HTTP verbs precisely?

Tags: architecture, rest, microservices, http

I'm concerned with the practices on my team regarding following REST and HTTP verbs precisely. For example, when we hit a get endpoint for a resource/resources that doesn't exist, we return a 404. Shouldn't we return an empty list with a 200? I thought 404 was reserved for a URL that didn't exist. Does your organization follow REST principles precisely? And how big of an issue is it? I feel like most organizations that profess REST eventually devolve in RPC.

Comment: Maybe the status code should be `204 No Content`? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9595184/2791540)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should micro services follow HTTP verbs precisely?

Yes.

> how big of an issue is it?

That will depend on a number of things, including how many different organizations are communicating with your micro service via this API, and how many general purpose components you intending to introduce.

> The REST interface is designed to be efficient for large-grain hypermedia data transfer, optimizing for the common case of the Web, but resulting in an interface that is not optimal for other forms of architectural interaction. -- [Fielding, 2000](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5)

When your microservice doesn't need to be "web scale", when the clients and servers are under shared control and can coordinate releases, then the case for precision starts to lean more on "best practices" than it does on consequences.

> For example, when we hit a get endpoint for a resource/resources that doesn't exist, we return a 404. Shouldn't we return an empty list with a 200? I thought 404 was reserved for a URL that didn't exist.

REST doesn't have endpoints, just resources ([Fielding, 2018](https://twitter.com/fielding/status/1052976631374000128?lang=en)).

The meaning of a 404 message is [standardized](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics#section-15.5.5):

> The *404 (Not Found)* status code indicates that the origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

What is not standardized: any implementation constraints on what defines a "current representation".

Which is to say, it is completely up to you, in defining your resource model, to decide for yourself when a "resource" has a current representation, and when it does not.  Which is to say, it's up to you to decide whether the body of the response is a representation of the resource, or if instead it is a representation of a client error.

---

For example, when I ask Google for a current representation of

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=250699d1-6711-4592-9d35-9643f1fb9cc2
```

The response returned to me has a 200 status code, so I know that the body of the response is a representation of this resource (which is to say, it is a document describing what pages in Google's index match this particular query).

The human readable text in that HTML document reads

```
Your search - 250699d1-6711-4592-9d35-9643f1fb9cc2 - did not match any documents.
```

And that's *fine*.  But it would be equally find for Google to instead return a response with a client error, if it wanted to assert that there was no resource matching the request-target I provided.

HTTP doesn't constrain an implementation in its choice of responses to send; it only constrains the semantics of those messages.